# How should I let Shake know that 'ghc --make' is needed to track changes to haskell files?

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I want to know the recommended way to use shake and `ghc --make` together.  In my project, the shake rules are used to compile C source code into their `*.o` files (which I call `cobjects`), and these objects are linked together into my haskell program by calling `ghc --make`.  During this command, `ghc` figures out for itself when it needs to rebuild my haskell files.

The example below isn't correctly written to integrate the two tools.  If a `.hs` file changes then rerunning the shake script won't re-invoke `ghc --make`.  I understand why shake doesn't know to rebuild, but I don't know the recommended fix.

```
main = shake shakeOptions $ do
  want [main_exe]

  main_exe *> \out -> do
    need cobjects
    cmd "ghc --make" hs_compileFlags cobjects "main.hs"

  cobjects **> ...
```

Comment: Question: when you say "when a .hs file changes" - do you mean "when `main.hs` changes`? or are there other .hs files involved? It seems to me that your rules for `main_exe` should have `needs "main.hs"` in it somewhere.

Comment: No, I mean "when any .hs file changes".  If `main.hs` is unchanged, but another source file `foo.hs` that `main.hs` depends on has changed, then the command `ghc --make` is smart enough to figure out by itself that it must recompile `main.hs` and whatever else depended on `foo.hs`.

Comment: Part of the answer might be in using `ghc -M` to have ghc emit dependency information -- see [this](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#makefile-dependencies) for more details. You could then incorporate that into a `needs` statement.

Comment: Instead of re-running `ghc --make` "when any .hs file changes", don't you want to always re-run `ghc --make`?  That seems necessary to re-link the executable, and then `ghc --make` should pick up any changes to .hs files as well.

Comment: Yes, I always want to run `ghc --make`.  It should run after (possibly) doing the rule for `cobjects`

Comment: @JohnL to run something "every time" you could do it with `action $ need [main_exe]; cmd "ghc --make" ...`, but it's not a good solution as Shake is no longer doing proper dependencies for anything you add downstream of `main_exe`. In addition, running `ghc --make` is actually quite slow (I have 0.003s vs 10s for some projects as `ghc --make` invokes the C pre processor and parses everything). Fortunately using `ghc -M` works well.

Answer (score 2):

The general principle is that if a rule runs a command that uses a file, it should depend on the file. In your case you must `need` all the things `ghc --make` requests, and the easiest way to figure that out is with `ghc -M` (which generates a `Makefile`):

```
main = shake shakeOptions $ do
  want [main_exe]

  main_exe *> \out -> do
    need cobjects
    cmd "ghc -M" hs_compileFlags "main.hs"
    cmd "ghc --make" hs_compileFlags cobjects "main.hs"
    needMakefileDependencies "Makefile"

  cobjects **> ...
```

The `needMakefileDependencies` function is in `Development.Shake.Util`. The only subtlety is that I call `needMakefileDependencies` *after* running the command, since otherwise the object files won't have been created yet (you could solve that by filtering only the `.hs` files in the `Makefile` using `parseMakefile` yourself).

Comment: It's not quite so simple as just `need`ing everything `ghc -M` requests.  You must also arrange to call `ghc` on every file that might need recompilation, which includes changes via `CPP`, changed compilation flags, template haskell's `addDependentFile` (`ghc -M` doesn't track this), and any time the package db has changed.  Also there are a few odd errors having to do with stale `.hi/.o` files if a source file has been deleted.  These may not be relevant to every project, but broken build systems are supremely frustrating so it's good to know about them.

Comment: As @JohnL says, `addDependentFile` won't work, and you might want to call `ghc --make` if the output of `ghc-pkg list` changes, which captures any package change. I don't think you need to call `ghc` on every file, since the `--make` mode will take care of that. There shouldn't be any errors with stale `.hi/.o` files, even if things have been deleted (other than ones stemming from `ghc --make` alone).

Comment: I agree, calling `ghc --make` should take care of all issues related to those problems.  I meant if you want to entirely avoid `ghc --make`, those are issues that you will need to manage yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like recommended way might be to use "phony" rule and add a `want` for that rule at the top.  This was found from this helpful tutorial:

http://blog.jle.im/entry/shake-task-automation-and-scripting-in-haskell

My first attempt at adapting this idea to my example:

```
main = shake shakeOptions $ do
  want [main_exe, "compile and link hs"]

  main_exe *> \out -> do
    need cobjects

  cobjects **> ...

  "compile and link hs" ~> do
    cmd "ghc --make" hs_compileFlags cobjects "main.hs"
```

The `(~>)` function specifies that the string `"compile and link hs"` is the name of a rule but not the name of a file.

While this will always attempt to run the new rule like I want, it unfortunately tries to run the rule before the rule for `main_exe` which *isn't* what I want.

Moving the demand for the new rule inside the rule for `main_exe` seems to fix this new problem:

```
main = shake shakeOptions $ do
  want [main_exe]

  main_exe *> \out -> do
    need cobjects
    need ["compile and link hs"]

  cobjects **> ...

  "compile and link hs" ~> do
    cmd "ghc --make" hs_compileFlags cobjects "main.hs"
```

Although this works I don't understand how Shake decides which order to run the two rules in the first piece of code.

Comment: In general it isn't a good idea to `need` a phony rule from a non-phony rule. I suspect if you replaced the `need ["compile and link hs"]` with the `cmd "ghc --make" ...` it would do exactly the same, which gets you back to what you had in the question.